# Processing - Weird behavior in IF statement

Tags: java, processing

I have this code.

```
if(infoDisplay.readChar() == SOH) {
  waitingForReturn = false;
  println("Got here 9");
  String inStr = infoDisplay.readStringUntil(EOT);
  inStr = inStr.substring(0,inStr.length()-1);
  println("Got here 10");
  print(inStr);
  println(" - Length: " + inStr.length());
  print(heartbeat);
  println(" - Length: " + heartbeat.length());
  if(inStr == heartbeat) {
    println("Got here 11");
    return true;
  } else {            
    println("Got here 12");//Retry
    return false;
  }
} else {
      return false;
}
```

And my console output looks like this

```
Got here 9
Got here 10
HEARTBEAT - Length: 9
HEARTBEAT - Length: 9
Got here 12
```

What is wrong here? The two variables prints out identical and with the same length?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With java Strings, you have to use `.equals()` for equality. What you are doing here is comparing their memory address and seeing if they are the same.

So your if statement should be `if (inStr.equals(heartbeat)) {`

Comment: Arh!! I knew that. Thanks.

Comment: This goes for any object in java. A problem that might occur that you have to watch out is when you are comparing `Integer`s, for example, that are not the same as the primitive counterpart `int`. It will work for some low numbers as they cache the objects to do less unboxing, but for higher value numbers it will fail as it will compare memory addresses.

Comment: also be aware that `BigDecimal` are better compared using `compareTo` (for example `BigDecimal.valueOf(0.0).equals(BigDecimal.ZERO)` is false, while `compareTo` will return `0` - `equals` also takes the scale into account)